# Issues with .TPL file with Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, counter, template-engine

I use PHP Melody on my site and I don't know how can I make one thing.

I have this code to print on index 30 post:

Code:

```
{get_advanced_video_list assignto="new_videos" limit="30"}  
{foreach from=$new_videos key=k item=video_data}
```

I need after 5 post to put a `div` (`div class="thumb-holder"`)

So there should be:

```
>div class="thumb-holder" post 1 post 2 post 3 post 4 post 5 /div><br>
>div class="thumb-holder" post6 post7 post8 post9 post10 /div><br>
>div class="thumb-holder" post11 post12 post13 post14 post15 /div><br>
>.........................<br>
>div class="thumb-holder" post26 post27 post28 post29 post30 /div <br>
```

I tried more things, but nothing has worked. What can I do?

PS: Is a .tpl file so outdated that it no longer works with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here exactly what you wish:

```
<div class="thumb-holder">
    {foreach from=$new_videos key=k item=video_data name=foo}
        {if $smarty.foreach.foo.index > 1 and $smarty.foreach.foo.index is div by 5}
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="thumb-holder">
        {/if}
        {$video_data}<br>
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work. I tried but nothing. Of course, i need to open <div class="thumb-holder"> outpul </div> . I tried with {else} but nothing happend :((

Comment: doesn't work. I tried but nothing. Of course, i need to open <div class="thumb-holder"> outpul post 1 post 2 post 3 post 4 post 5 </div> . I tried with {else} but nothing happend :((

Comment: the problem is this : I need to open <div class> after 5 post close the </div> and open another <div class="thumb-holder"> 5 post</div> ..if i close the first div after 1 post is not ok, i need to close after only 5 post and repeat procedure. here is my try: http://pastebin.com/5nrPP9sG

Comment: Try `{if $smarty.foreach.n.index > 1 and $smarty.foreach.n.index is div by 5}`

Comment: Done. Updated here, and updated at runnable. You can check it. That's it?)

Comment: yes, that's it. Thanks so much! I tried to make work for 2 days and nothing. Thanks very much!

Comment: welcome any time!) i glad, that this example help you!)

Answer (score 0):

```
{foreach from=$entries key=i item=topic name=foo}
  {if $smarty.foreach.foo.index == 10}
    {break}
  {/if}
  {if $topic.topic_style == question}
    <li>
      <a href="topic.php?id={$topic.id}">{$topic.title}</a>
    </li>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid index checking on every loop, use [array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk) to split your array into smaller chunks with exact amount of items you need:

```
{assign var=video_groups value=$new_videos|array_chunk:5:true}
{foreach from=$video_groups item=video_group}
<div class="thumb-holder">
    {foreach from=$video_group item=video_data key=k}
        <img id="{$k}" src="{$video_data}" /> 
    {/foreach}
</div>
{/foreach}
```